# Change the color of blinking in the taskbar using FlashWindowEx

Tags: windows, taskbar, blink, flashwindowex

Is it possible to change the color of the blinking in the taskbar in FlashWindowEx by programmation. I know you can change it if you change your theme.

Comment: You do not control the blink color, but you can add an overlay to your taskbar button if you want to convey state information.

Comment: @RaymondChen Do you know know what that is called? I want to read more about it?

Comment: Do a Web search for taskbar button overlay.